# Tomcat 7.0.32 fails to start up

Tags: java, tomcat7

After dropping my WAR file into the webapps directory and typing the following command -

> catalina.bat jpda start

The Tomcat window appears for a split second and then disappears.
Upon further review of the logs files here is the jist of the stack trace -

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.<clinit>(Catalina.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    .
    .
    .
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager
```

I have a feeling this is due to the fact that Tomcat cannot find my JVM, but I'm not certain.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Such a stacktrace is provided by the JVM, so the JVM is found and Tomcat begins to start, but fails for another reason. Have you made some modifications in Tomcat installation ?

Comment: Try agai with a freshly unzipped distribution.

Comment: @ Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - Right on. I grabbed the latest distrubution, 7.0.40, and it worked!  *headscratch*  I'll chalk this one up as a fluke. Good suggestion.

Comment: That was also the case for me, where I needed instead of Tomcat v8 Tomcat v7. The first installation didn't work, the second download was fine. But I do not know what I did wrong to get that error.